# Equivalence testing for 3 means with different sample sizes (corrected Welch TOST?)

Tags: multiple-comparisons, equivalence

I have three groups and three variables for each (with different scales), and am in need of testing for differences across the groups for each variable.
My approach would consist in a Welch TOST equivalence test using the TOSTER R package and the correction for multiple comparisons suggested here:https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2800314/

Would it be more correct to perform an ANOVA first and treat the pairwise corrected TOST as a post hoc test? Or, as my intention is to test for equivalence, would it be more appropriate to only perform the TOST?

I have also considered the regression-based method shown in example 3 of this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5856600/
Given my number of groups and variables it does not seem appropriate.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/help.